# How to utilize data in xml from flow monitor

Tags: ns-3

I want to use ns3 to calculate TCP throughput,and I think one way to track network status is using flow monitor.However,it gives out xml file and I do not know how to use it...Can anyone help how to use the data or how to find relative tutorials of utilizing data generated by flow monitor in ns3 document?

Comment: FlowMonitor gives you `timeFirstRxPacket `, `timeLastTxPacket `, and `rxBytes`. See [here](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/flow-monitor.html). You can easily calculate throughput with those values.
Also, there are examples that plot the throughput

Answer (score 1):

The data in FlowMonitor.xml can be viewed using NetAnimator.

1. Install [NetAnim](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/NetAnim), see the requirements
2. Add the netanim-module libraries in your simulation code
3. Configure the node animations, see the example in src/netanim/examples/grid-animation.cc

   `std::string animFile = "grid-animation.xml";
   AnimationInterface anim (animFile);`
4. Run the simulation
5. Open the Netanim folder and run `./NetAnim`
6. [Open XML trace file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UJlI.png)
7. On the Stats tab change the IP-MAC switch to Flow-monitor
8. [Select flow-monitor file and open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kU74.png)
9. [Select the flows of your interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7rI7.png)

Ready! Good simulations!